# "compiling error" FreeRTOS Arduino Library with Visual Studio 2015 and Visual Micro plugin

Tags: arduino, freertos

I have recently installed MS Visual Studio 2015 with the Arduino plugin "Visual Micro".
Everything works fine, upload a sketch etc. Except when I try to compile my code when I use FreeRTOS. I downloaded the FreeRTOS libary through the Arduino IDE (library manager). Therefore(in MS VS 2015) I could chose to include the library in MS VS 2015. So I included the library in one of my sketches. Below you see my code example. Within the Arduino IDE i can compile the code and upload it to the device, but in MS VS there are some errors.

```
#include <timers.h>
#include <task.h>
#include <StackMacros.h>
#include <semphr.h>
#include <queue.h>
#include <projdefs.h>
#include <portmacro.h>
#include <portable.h>
#include <mpu_wrappers.h>
#include <list.h>
#include <FreeRTOSVariant.h>
#include <FreeRTOSConfig.h>
#include <event_groups.h>
#include <croutine.h>
#include <Arduino_FreeRTOS.h>

//define Tasks
void TaskBlinkSlow(void *pvParameters);
void TaskBlinkFast(void *pvParameters);

void setup()
{
  /* add setup code here */
    xTaskCreate(TaskBlinkSlow, "TaskSlow", 128, NULL, 1, NULL);
    xTaskCreate(TaskBlinkFast, "TaskFast", 128, NULL, 2, NULL);
    pinMode(13, OUTPUT);

}

void loop()
{
  //Empty, things are done in tasks!!!
}

void TaskBlinkSlow(void * pvParameters)
{
    for (;;) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            digitalWrite(13, HIGH);   
            delay(1000); 
            digitalWrite(13, LOW);  
            delay(1000);
        }
        
        vTaskDelay(5000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS); 
    }
}

void TaskBlinkFast(void * pvParameters)
{
    for (;;) {
        digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
        delay(500);
        digitalWrite(13, LOW);
        delay(500);
    }
}
```

At the end of this post you will find the short snippet of the compilers error log. Maybe someone already came around the same issue and has a quick fix.

> An example debugger breakpoint has been created. To switch the demo
> breakpoint off, deselect Visual Micro>Tutorial Mode.
>
> Compiling debug version of 'FreeRTOS' for 'Arduino/Genuino Uno'
> FreeRTOS.ino:In file included from timers.h:75:3: error: #error
> "include Arduino_FreeRTOS.h must appear in source files before include
> timers.h" :#error "include Arduino_FreeRTOS.h must appear in source
> files before include timers.h" timers.h:In file included from
> FreeRTOS.ino:from task.h:75:3: error: #error "include
> Arduino_FreeRTOS.h must appear in source files before include task.h"
> :#error "include Arduino_FreeRTOS.h must appear in source files before
> include task.h" task.h:In file included from timers.h:from
> FreeRTOS.ino:from list.h:99:3: error: #error Arduino_FreeRTOS.h must
> be included before list.h :#error Arduino_FreeRTOS.h must be included
> before list.h FreeRTOS.ino:In file included from semphr.h:74:3: error:
>
> ## error "include Arduino_FreeRTOS.h" must appear in source files before "include semphr.h" :#error "include Arduino_FreeRTOS.h" must appear in
>
> source files before "include semphr.h" semphr.h:In file included from
> FreeRTOS.ino:from queue.h:75:3: error: #error "include
> Arduino_FreeRTOS.h" must appear in source files before "include
> queue.h" :#error "include Arduino_FreeRTOS.h" must appear in source
> files before "include queue.h" FreeRTOS.ino:In file included from
> list.h:99:3: error: #error Arduino_FreeRTOS.h must be included before
> list.h :#error Arduino_FreeRTOS.h must be included before list.h
> task.h:In file included from timers.h:from FreeRTOS.ino:from
> list.h:184:22: error: 'TickType_t' does not name a type
> :configLIST_VOLATILE TickType_t xItemValue;   *< The value being
> listed.  In most cases this is used to sort the list in descending
> order. * list.h:196:22: error: 'TickType_t' does not name a type
> :configLIST_VOLATILE TickType_t xItemValue list.h:208:22: error:
> 'UBaseType_t' does not name a type :configLIST_VOLATILE UBaseType_t
> uxNumberOfItems list.h:386:47: error: expected initializer before
> 'PRIVILEGED_FUNCTION :void vListInitialise( List_t * const pxList )
> PRIVILEGED_FUNCTION list.h:397:55: error: expected initializer before
> 'PRIVILEGED_FUNCTION :void vListInitialiseItem( ListItem_t * const
> pxItem ) PRIVILEGED_FUNCTION list.h:410:77: error: expected
> initializer before 'PRIVILEGED_FUNCTION :void vListInsert( List_t *
> const pxList, ListItem_t * const pxNewListItem ) PRIVILEGED_FUNCTION
> list.h:431:80: error: expected initializer before 'PRIVILEGED_FUNCTION
> :void vListInsertEnd( List_t * const pxList, ListItem_t * const
> pxNewListItem ) PRIVILEGED_FUNCTION list.h:446:1: error: 'UBaseType_t'
> does not name a type :UBaseType_t uxListRemove( ListItem_t * const
> pxItemToRemove ) PRIVILEGED_FUNCTION timers.h:In file included from
> FreeRTOS.ino:from task.h:109:20: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of
> 'BaseType_t' with no type [-fpermissive] :typedef BaseType_t
> (*TaskHookFunction_t)( void * ) task.h:109:20: error: typedef
> 'BaseType_t' is initialized (use decltype instead) task.h:109:22:
> error: 'TaskHookFunction_t' was not declared in this scope :typedef
> BaseType_t (*TaskHookFunction_t)( void * ) timers.h:In file included
> from FreeRTOS.ino:from task.h:136:2: error: 'BaseType_t' does not name
> a type :BaseType_t xOverflowCount task.h:137:2: error: 'TickType_t'
> does not name a type :TickType_t xTimeOnEntering task.h:146:2: error:
> 'uint32_t' does not name a type :uint32_t ulLengthInBytes
> task.h:147:2: error: 'uint32_t' does not name a type :uint32_t
> ulParameters task.h:155:2: error: 'TaskFunction_t' does not name a
> type :TaskFunction_t pvTaskCode task.h:157:2: error: 'uint16_t' does
> not name a type :uint16_t usStackDepth task.h:159:2: error:
> 'UBaseType_t' does not name a type :UBaseType_t uxPriority
> task.h:160:2: error: 'StackType_t' does not name a type :StackType_t
> *puxStackBuffer task.h:161:27: error: 'portNUM_CONFIGURABLE_REGIONS' was not declared in this scope :MemoryRegion_t xRegions[
> portNUM_CONFIGURABLE_REGIONS ] task.h:170:2: error: 'UBaseType_t' does
> not name a type :UBaseType_t xTaskNumber;  * A number unique to the
> task. * task.h:172:2: error: 'UBaseType_t' does not name a type
> :UBaseType_t uxCurrentPriority; * The priority at which the task was
> running (may be inherited) when the structure was populated. *
> task.h:173:2: error: 'UBaseType_t' does not name a type :UBaseType_t
> uxBasePriority;  * The priority to which the task will return if the
> task's current priority has been inherited to avoid unbounded priority
> inversion when obtaining a mutex.  Only valid if configUSE_MUTEXES is
> defined as 1 in FreeRTOSConfig.h. * timers.h:In file include

Comment: Might I suggest you mark Feilipiu-s answer as the solution? Or yours, I guess, if you feel that was clearer?

Answer (score 2):

If you read the error messages, the issue is explained clearly.

include Arduino_FreeRTOS.h must appear first.

Your example shows it included last.
Put it first and the errors will go away.

Arduino_FreeRTOS.h includes many definitions that are used in other places, hence the need for it to be first.

Unrelated to your question, but using delay() is nasty as it consumes CPU cycles needlessly. Try vTaskDelay() as alternative which defers (or blocks) to the Scheduler to unblock other Tasks or run the idle Task which is the Arduino loop() function.

The loop() function can then put the CPU to sleep, reducing power consumption. See the feilipu.me post on topic for more.

vTaskDelay() counts Ticks, so hence the need to divide by the Tick period in milliseconds. i.e.
Time in ms / portTICK_PERIOD_MS = Ticks

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <Arduino_FreeRTOS.h>
#include <croutine.h>
#include <event_groups.h>
#include <FreeRTOSConfig.h>
#include <FreeRTOSVariant.h>
#include <list.h>
#include <mpu_wrappers.h>
#include <portable.h>
#include <portmacro.h>
#include <projdefs.h>
#include <queue.h>
#include <semphr.h>
#include <Stack_Macros.h>
#include <task.h>
#include <timers.h>


void setup()
{

}

void loop() 
{

}
```

Comment: While your code might offer a solution to the problem, please explain how this solves the problem instead of just placing the code.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, the includes where in the wrong order: dont know why;).
You cant only include freeRTOS in MS VS you need to correct the order of the includes by yourself.

Here is the correct order:

```
#include <Arduino_FreeRTOS.h>
#include <croutine.h>
#include <event_groups.h>
#include <FreeRTOSConfig.h>
#include <FreeRTOSVariant.h>
#include <list.h>
#include <mpu_wrappers.h>
#include <portable.h>
#include <portmacro.h>
#include <projdefs.h>
#include <queue.h>
#include <semphr.h>
#include <StackMacros.h>
#include <task.h>
#include <timers.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the Arduino code you are referring to, but normally there is no reason to include [FreeRTOSConfig.h](http://www.freertos.org/a00110.html) directly - instead include FreeRTOS.h first, and that will get the ordering of the port layer files and FreeRTOSConfig.h files correct for you, then include the header files that contain the API functions you want to use.

Comment: In the Arduino IDE all .h files found in the src directory of the library are added to the sketch when it is included. This is a bit messy. The only mandatory include is Arduino_FreeRTOS.h. Other includes are needed only when the features are used.